# SSL Certificate to JSON

Tags: json, unix, escaping, ssl-certificate

I need to send a SSL Certificate as a string via JSON to my server. On the server I need to reconstruct the JSON string to a valid certificate. My problems are the spaces and line brakes in the certificate.

How can I preserve the correct format of the certificate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was indeed related to the white spaces and line breaks.

Here is what worked for me:

1. Copied the certificate into a one line text field. Not very elegant but it's a quick way to make a one line string out of it. Most text editors can do that too, i guess.
2. Replaced the line breaks (now white spaces) with "\n". Do not replace the white spaces between those phrases `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` they can stay as they are.

Example:

```
{
"key": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\njlQvt9WdR9Vpg3WQT5+C3HU17bUOwvhp/r0+viMcBUCRW85UqI2BJJKTi1IwQQ4c\ntyTrhYJYOP+A6JXt5BzDzZy/B7tjEMDBosPiwH2m4MaP+6wTbi1qR1pFDL3fXYDr\n"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to base64 encode the certificate at client and decode it on server. This avoids all the hassle of adding line breaks yet preserving the formatting,
similar to kubernetes secrets

Comment: This is the most automat-able answer, just remember to use `base64 -w 0` so base64 doesn't generate newlines either

Answer (score 0):

I would offer a more nuanced explanation.  json-serialized strings escape newlines and some other characters.  But a json string can hold a PEM-encoded certificate without issue.  The only trouble that comes about here is that some work must be done to hand-construct the json.  I would not recommend that approach though.  This use case can be easily supported with common tools.  For instance, the following shows retrieval of a certificate, embedding within json, parsing the json, extraction of the certificate and ultimately parsing by openssl:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM | python3 -c "
import sys
import json
body = {}
body['cert'] = sys.stdin.read()
json.dump(body, sys.stdout)
" | python3 -c "
import sys
import json
body = json.load(sys.stdin)
print(body['cert'])
" | openssl x509 -text; echo $?
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            fa:bc:89:f7:bf:33:10:94:0a:00:00:00:01:25:fd:32
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
...
0
```