# How to have multiple lines in post body in Postman?

Tags: json, postman

how do I get linebreaks in a json request body in Postman? 
I want to send the following body (raw, application/json) in a POST request in Postman:

```
{"csrRequest":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICwzCCAasCAQAwfjELMAkGA1UEBhMCc3YxEjAQBgNVBAgMCVN
0b2NraG9sbTESUEBwwJU3RvY2tob2xtMRMfandMuchMoreLines
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----" }
```

I've tried putting everything in one line and forcing the line breaks with \n, \r\n and other similar combinations, but all I get out on the wire is the escaped combinations replaced with space, no line breaks what so ever.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently when I was trying to pass a PEM certificate through postman (raw, application/json) inside a JSON as a String by using a POST method. I found in this solution [here]: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14580203/4576242) that I had to remove all the line breaks and replace them with \n. So if we assume that this was my certificate:

```
{
   "certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                  blah_blah_blah
                  MIICwzCCAasCAQAwfjELMAkGA1UEBhMCc3YxEjAQBgNVBAgMCVN
                  0b2NraG9sbTESUEBwwJU3RvY2tob2xtMRMfandMuchMoreLines
                  blah_blah_blah
                  -----END CERTIFICATE-----"
}
```

I had to transform it into this:

```
{
   "certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nblah_blah_blah\nMIICwzCCAasCAQAwfjELMAkGA1UEBhMCc3YxEjAQBgNVBAgMCVN\n0b2NraG9sbTESUEBwwJU3RvY2tob2xtMRMfandMuchMoreLines\nblah_blah_blah\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just write what you want in notepad or any text editor and copy it and paste in postman field

I tested this with postman version 7.29.1 and it worked

Comment: That didn't work for me.