# Not able to access kubernetes api from inside a pod container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-pod

I have created a hashicorp vault deployment and configured kubernetes auth. The vault container calls kubernetes api internally from the pod to do k8s authentication, and that call is failing with 500 error code (connection refused). I am using docker for windows kubernetes.

I added the below config to vault for kubernetes auth mechanism.

**payload.json**

```
{
    "kubernetes_host": "http://kubernetes",
    "kubernetes_ca_cert": <k8s service account token>
}
```

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: <vault root token>" --request POST --data @payload.json http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/config
```

I got 204 response as expected.

And I created a role for kubernetes auth using which I am trying to login to vault:

**payload2.json**

```
{
    "role": "tanmoy-role",
    "jwt": "<k8s service account token>"
}
```

```
curl --request POST --data @payload2.json http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
```

The above curl is giving below response:

> {"errors":["Post http://kubernetes/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1/tokenreviews: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:80: connect: connection refused"]}

Below is my kubernetes service up and running properly and I can also access kubernetes dashboard by using proxy.

```
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP              PORT(S)                         AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>                   443/TCP                         13d
```

I am not able to figure out why 'kubernetes' service is not accessible from inside the container. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1.** My vault pod and service are working fine:

**service**

```
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP              PORT(S)                         AGE
vault-elb-int   LoadBalancer   10.104.197.76   localhost,192.168.0.10   8200:31650/TCP,8201:31206/TCP   26h
```

**Pod**

```
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
vault-84c65db6c9-pj6zw   1/1     Running   0          21h
```

**Edit 2.**
As John suggested, I changed the 'kubernetes_host' in payload.json to 'https://kubernetes'. But now I am getting this error:

```
{"errors":["Post https://kubernetes/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1/tokenreviews: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"]}
```

Comment: could you please post your service list and pod list related to this question?

Comment: Hi @Ajay, I added pad and service list. Please note these are working fine without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured out what went wrong:

my payload.json content was wrong

it should be like this:

```
{
      "kubernetes_host": "https://kubernetes",
      "kubernetes_ca_cert": <kubectl exec to vault pod and cat  /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt, now make the cert one line by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14580203/2054147>
}
```

Now below endpoint is working fine and returning the desire client_token

```
curl --request POST --data @payload2.json http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
```

Thanks @John for helping me to figure out the initial issue with kubernetes_host.

Answer (score 2):

Your login request is being sent to the `tokenreview` endpoint on port 80.  I think this is because your `kubernetes_host` specifies a `http` URL.  The 500 response is because it's not listening on port 80, but on 443 instead (as you can see in your service list output).

Try changing to `https` when configuring the auth, i.e.

```
payload.json

{
    "kubernetes_host": "https://kubernetes",
    "kubernetes_ca_cert": <k8s service account token>
}
```

Comment: Hi @John, I changed http to https,  but now I got this error message with 500 error code: {"errors":["Post https://kubernetes/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1/tokenreviews: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"]}

Comment: When using `curl`, pass in `-k` or the long form `--insecure` to have `curl` trust self-signed certs.

Comment: Hi @gears i added --insecure but still it fails because the https endpoint which is failing is getting called internally. I am not calling that endpoint directly, so no option for me to pass --insecure to that call.

Comment: @tanmoy this is a completely separate error and is due to your Vault container not trusting the certificate that Kubernetes is using to serve up the HTTPS endpoints.  You need to add the CA certificate that was used to sign the Kubernetes certificate to Vault, so that Vault will trust Kubernetes. See [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/kubernetes.html#configuration) for details on how to do this.  If you get stuck, close this question and create another question and we can help you there.

Comment: Hi @John, I have already configured the K8s auth for vault similar way provided in the link you shared above. As you said, I am closing this question and created another question with this specific issue. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/59456946/2054147

Comment: this issue got resolved. Anyone interested please see my answer below.