# How can I resolve self sign certificate issue on unix for secure channel

Tags: unix, kubernetes, docker-for-windows, hashicorp-vault

I am using kubernetes provided by docker for windows. There I deployed a component Hashicorp Vault. Vault internally calls kubernetes api to authenticate kubernetes login for vault. When I am calling the vault api to fetch client token, it is failing with below 500 error:

```
{"errors":["Post https://kubernetes/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1/tokenreviews: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
```

endpoint I am calling:

```
curl --request POST --data @payload3.json http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
```

Please see this question posted by me earlier to get the context: [Not able to access kubernetes api from inside a pod container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59408875/2054147)

Seems like it is an issue with unix so added unix tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This issue got resolved, Anyone interested please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59470261/2054147

Comment: @sethvargo this question was posted by me only :) , and the accepted answer in that question solved my issue.